# Why Google Play reviewing team changed my app content rating

Tags: android, google-play

Google play reviewing team changed content rating of my app from **everyone** to **low maturity** by mentioning as my app includes gambling themes.

I never found such gambling themes in my app [Pro Kabaddi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartinfolab.prokabaddi)

In this i implemented quick link to see points table, Match Fixtures and video from starsports.com

Please tell me what are the gambling themes my app includes because i don't found any thing seems to gampling.

i received mail from google play team as below..

"
This is a notification that the minimum content level of your application, Pro Kabaddi, with package ID com.smartinfolab.prokabaddi, has been changed to Low Maturity (2) by the Google Play Team after a regular review.

REASON FOR CONTENT LEVEL CHANGE: Violation of the Google Play content rating policy.

After a regular review, we have determined that your app includes gambling themes. The content rating of your app has been changed to reflect this content.

Please be advised that additional content rating modifications by the Google Play Team may result in administrative action, up to and including removal of subsequent applications in violation.

All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts.

We appreciate your contributions towards ensuring an accurate content rating experience for Google Play users.
"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Play Store terms and their enforcement, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact Google Play developer support and ask them why they have reclassified your app content rating, but since your app is sports related and appears to contain advertising, I'd say it's likely that when the Google Play content team demoed your app an advert appeared for a gambling site or app. As advertising (whether third-party or not) is considered part of your app content, this would explain why it has been reclassified. Perhaps you could change the settings of your advertising to not show anything gambling related, it might affect your advertising revenue, but you should be able to get your app reclassified as suitable for everyone.